# number of real roots of equation involving derivative and double derivative

Tags: calculus

> Let $k:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that $ k(a)=k(e)=0 ,k(b)=k(d)=2 , k(c)=1$, where $a<b<c<d<e$.
>
> Find the minimum number of solutions of $(k'(x))^2+k(x)k''(x)=0$ in $[a,e]$.

Try:  By drawing Rough graph. We have  $k(x)=0$ for $x=a,b$.

and for $K'(x)=0$ for at least $3$ values of $x$

And we can write $(k'(x))^2+k(x)k''(x)=(k(x)\cdot k'(x))'$

so from above data we have $k(x)\cdot k'(x)=0$ for at least $5$  values of $x$

so using Rolles theorem , we have $(k'(x))^2+k(x)k''(x)=0$ for at least $4$ values of $x$

could some please explain me , whats wrong in my solution, thanks

Comment: Why do You think that it's wrong?

Comment: Taking a polynomial as test function then $k(x)$ is a fourth degree polynomial and $(k')^2+k k''$ should be a sixth degree polynomial with parameters $a,b,c,d,e$ Surely in such case we can find a $k(a,b,c,d,e;x)$ with no real zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine.

Moreover, if you let $$k(x)=-x^6+ 2x^2+1$$

then the requirements are satisfied with

$(a,b,c,d,e)=(-\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}},-1,0,1,\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}})$,

and there are only $4$ points where $k'^2+kk''$ vanishes on $[a,e]$.

This shows that $4$ is a sharp lower bound.